# Reinstallation OSX Mavericks on Mac Mini via WiFi Fails

Tags: install

Tried to upgrade to OSX Yosemite on my Mac Mini bought this year running OSX Mavericks. It failed. When I checked for issues using Disk Utility I saw:

> Disk Utility stopped repairing "Macintosh HD" Disk Utility can't repair
>   this disk. Backup as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk
>   and restore your backed-up files

This was due to the error `unable to bootstrap transaction group 259092 invalid field value`

So I erased all and tried an internet recovery with recovery partition. I made my wifi connection open to all, but I still get

> OSX cannot be reinstalled because you are not connected to the
>   internet. If you connect to the internet via Wifi use the menu with
>   the wifi icon to select the network. Otherwise plug in an ethernet
>   cable.

I could plug into my wireless router I guess, but as I do not have a mobile screen for my Mac Mini I cannot see what I am doing.

Why does OSX not just connect to the wireless network as it is open? Any way to make it work? Is there an option to start with the basic OSX Recovery Package and activate wifi and then start the upgrade to the full package?

Comment: I don't know about wifi connection, but you can download Yosemite from another device and restore your MacMini with a recovery usb like this : http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how-to-create-a-recovery-usb-drive

Comment: Read http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718 and decided to go back to WPA. Now it did continue and says it is downloading components, but it also says it will take 24 hours..? Not sure if it is working. Does the recovery partition remember the password then as well? We shall see.

Comment: @MrMojoRisin Rovery Disk Assistant - dowload link http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433 - on my MBP will create a disk to recover my OSX Lion System. The Mac Mini started with Mavericks. The current MBP has Mavericks too, but started with Lion. Wonder how I can create a Mavericks disk..

Comment: Will download Yosemite from App store and not install it and then try to use Diskmaker X http://liondiskmaker.com/ to make an installation usb disk. We shall see..

Comment: FYI Will follow tutorial here http://www.macworld.com/article/2367748/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-10-yosemite-install-drive.html . Will keep wifi installation Mavericks going on Mac Mini just in case it miraculously works out. But will probably install from usb.

Comment: You don't need Dismaker X for doing an installation usb disk ;) Just write this line on a Terminal Window : sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/YOUR_DISK --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app --nointeraction
http://www.macworld.com/article/2367748/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-10-yosemite-install-drive.html

Comment: Mmmm sorry I had not seen your last comment ^^

Comment: Pressed Alt at start, started from USB Bootable installer. Yosemite installation got going. Got stuck at "OSX could not be installed on your computer. Storage system verify or repair failed" Restarted and tried repair and it failed again. So it seems I am stuck. Will see if I can get it to Apple Care tomorrow. If someone has other tools to get beyond this type of error do let me know. But perhaps I just need a new HDD?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18115/discussion-between-rhand-and-mrmojorisin).

Comment: Seems I cannot use chat because I do not have enough points there or there is another issue. Just had a blinking folder with a question mark on restart now so it seems like a complete hard disk failure. Taking it to Apple Care tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a loose cable to my fusion hard disk. Apple Care fixed it. They re-attached it and now we are all good.